# How can I serialize object without some property names

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, serialization

I want to generate the following json output.I tried to serialize object but as you see from output there is no json string name for "data" array, If its serialized it will add the property name to array. Please suggest a solution for this and optimize it in generic way.This is dummy data orginal Data will be dynamic.

```
[
    {
        "data": [[0, -74984809.4603082], [1, -1547043466.02543], [2, 1197200673.15602], [3, -1329017076.87315]],
        "label": "Sine Wave"
    },
    {
        "data": [[0, -16009669.0446502], [1, -1349266386.03401], [2, 1730901576.10012], [3, -48303271.446511]],
        "label": "Cosine Wave"
    },
    {
        "data": [[0, -22114801.1769572], [1, 1737206285.30856], [2, 1280894300.93367], [3, -14969166.212896]],
        "label": "Sine2 Wave"
    },
    {
        "data": [[0, -236097551.627018], [1, 8971833.78377865], [2, -805237017.202245], [3, -28865332.2392996]],
        "label": "Cosine2 Wave"
    }
]
```

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;

namespace D3WebApp
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        public class Datum
        {
            public int No { get; set; }

            public double Value { get; set; }
        }
        public class LineGraphData
        {
            public Datum Data { get; set; }

            public string Label { get; set; }
        }

        public class GraphData
        {
            public Datum[] Data { get; set; }

            public string Label { get; set; }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetData()
        {
            return GetDataForChart(); ;
        }

        private static string GetDataForChart()
        {
            var r1 = new Random();
            var r2 = new Random();
            var r3 = new Random();
            var r4 = new Random();
            var datalist = new List<LineGraphData>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {

                datalist.Add(new LineGraphData()
                {
                    Data = new Datum()
                    {
                        No = i,
                        Value = r1.Next() * Math.Sin(r2.Next() + i / (10 * (r4.Next() + .5)))
                    },
                    Label = "Sine Wave"
                });

                datalist.Add(new LineGraphData()
                {
                    Data = new Datum()
                    {
                        No = i,
                        Value = r2.Next() * Math.Sin(r3.Next() + i / (10 * (r3.Next() + .5)))
                    },
                    Label = "Cosine Wave"
                });
                datalist.Add(new LineGraphData()
                {
                    Data = new Datum()
                    {
                        No = i,
                        Value = r3.Next() * Math.Sin(r1.Next() + i / (10 * (r2.Next() + .5)))
                    },
                    Label = "Sine2 Wave"
                });

                datalist.Add(new LineGraphData()
                {
                    Data = new Datum()
                    {
                        No = i,
                        Value = r4.Next() * Math.Sin(r4.Next() + i / (10 * (r1.Next() + .5)))
                    },
                    Label = "Cosine2 Wave"
                });
            }

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var valuelist = new List<GraphData>();
            //want to remove this or make it cleaner
            foreach (var result in datalist.DistinctBy(x => x.Label).Select(x => x.Label))
            {
                var childItems = datalist.
                    Where(x => x.Label == result).Select(x => x.Data).ToList();

                valuelist.Add(new GraphData() { Label = result, Data = childItems.ToArray() });

                sb.Append(@"{""data"":");
                sb.Append("[");

                foreach (var value in childItems)
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format("[{0},{1}],", value.No, value.Value));
                }

                var index = sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(',');

                if (index >= 0)
                    sb.Remove(index, 1);

                sb.Append("],");
                sb.Append(string.Format(@"""{0}"":""{1}""", "label", result));
                sb.Append("},");
            }
            var testdata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(valuelist);
            var datastr = "[" + sb.ToString().Trim(',') + "]";
            return datastr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not manually build json, you should use Json.Net serializer or similar

Comment: Is it possible to remove property name from output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use  [Newtonsoft.JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm) and Linq method GroupBy here:

```
    var datalistDynamic = datalist.GroupBy(it => it.Label).Select(
        dataItemGrouped => new
        {
            Label = dataItemGrouped.Key,
            Data = dataItemGrouped.Select(dataItem => new[] {dataItem.Data.No, dataItem.Data.Value})
        }).ToArray();
    var datastr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datalistDynamic);
    return datastr;
```

and this code can be removed:

```
   var sb = new StringBuilder();
            var valuelist = new List<GraphData>();
            //want to remove this or make it cleaner
            foreach (var result in datalist.DistinctBy(x => x.Label).Select(x => x.Label))
            {
                var childItems = datalist.
                    Where(x => x.Label == result).Select(x => x.Data).ToList();

                valuelist.Add(new GraphData() { Label = result, Data = childItems.ToArray() });

                sb.Append(@"{""data"":");
                sb.Append("[");

                foreach (var value in childItems)
                {
                    sb.Append(string.Format("[{0},{1}],", value.No, value.Value));
                }

                var index = sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(',');

                if (index >= 0)
                    sb.Remove(index, 1);

                sb.Append("],");
                sb.Append(string.Format(@"""{0}"":""{1}""", "label", result));
                sb.Append("},");
            }
            var testdata = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(valuelist);
            var datastr = "[" + sb.ToString().Trim(',') + "]";
```

If you want to ignore property, please use attribute `JsonIgnore`, for example

```
  public class GraphData
    {
        public Datum[] Data { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Label { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How can I remove x,y names from serialized string {"Data":{"x":0,"y":-707488064.82221842},"Label":"Sine2 Wave"},{"Data":{"x":0,"y":-1627302835.6074553},"Label":"Cosine2 Wave"}, name Data should be there but x,y should't.

Comment: Put JsonIgnore attribute on x and y properties in Data class

Comment: it will completely ignore, I just want to remove the name.  It should be like  {"Data":{:0,:-707488064.82221842},"Label":"Sine2 Wave"},{"Data":{:0,:-1627302835.6074553},"Label":"Cosi‌​ne2 Wave"}, value should be there without property name in it.

Comment: @shijithmc that is not valid json

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have Json output after serialization like posted in your question. You should follow this class hierarchy:

```
public class Sample
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<List<double>> Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

And then you should create array of samples which should be serialized via Json.Net

```
var samples = new List<Sample>();
samples.Add(new Sample()
{
    Data = new List<List<double>>()
    {
        new List<double> { 0, 6.48 },
        new List<double> { 1, 6.43 }
        //...other values
    },
    Label = "Port-1"
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(samples);
```

Comment: This allows only one value, I need x and y like [1,9] we cannot have list like    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public List<List<double>, List<double>> Data { get; set; } correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @shijithmc you are wrong, since you need array of arrays to conform posted json structure. In your case, you have to create array of points (x,y) (i.e. Data property). However, each point is represented by array of two elements (1st element is x, 2nd element is y).

Comment: Can you please provide a sample how can I add [{"data":[[0,6.48],[1,6.43],[2,6.43],[3,6.45],[4,6.44],[5,6.40],[6,6.43],[7,6.43],[8,6.40],[9,0.21],[13,5.39],[14,1.69],[15,8.75]],"label":"Port-1"} both x and y

Comment: @shijithmc I've edited initial example, as you can see maybe proposed Json structure doesn't suit your needs the best. If you have possibility, I strongly recommend you to change your json structure.